# write jquery cookie to sqlite | localhost django

Tags: jquery, django, sqlite, cookies

What is the best way to write this jquery.cookie to SQLite database? (without form of course)

**$.cookie('cart') =**

```
"[{"name":"Cinnamon bun","image":"/static/images/items/bakery/cinnamon_bun.jpg",
"price":" 5 uah","quantity":"2","alias":"cinnamon"},
{"name":"Croissant","image":"/static/images/items/bakery/croissant.jpg",
"price":" 10 uah","quantity":"1","alias":"croissant"},
{"name":"Donut","image":"/static/images/items/bakery/donuts.jpg",
"price":" 7 uah","quantity":"4","alias":"donut"},
{"name":"Chocolate chip cookies","image":"/static/images/items/bakery/cookies.gif",
"price":" 30 uah","quantity":"2","alias":"cookies"}]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are 2 possibilities:

1. using a simple_tag (custom template tags)

Thanks to it you don't have to worry which a URL user will visit. Codes written below will be run every single request.

Docs [HERE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/). (Note: it's for the version 1.8, if you are using a different version of Django, don't forget switch the docs).

Your codes should look like this: (in a python file inside templatetags/ folder)

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def your_name_of_this_function(context):
    """
    What is this tag about? (your comment)
    """
    request = context["request"]

    # Get cookies
    cookies = request.cookies["cart"]

    # Your codes for writing new lines into your models into your SQlite DB
    # if they are not in DB (the cookies)
    ...
```

More about requests [HERE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/). Note: cookies are in the form of dictionary

Then add this line to your "base.html" at the top:

```
{% load your_name_of_your_tag_script_without_dot_py %}
```

and somewhere (still "base.html") this: (e. g. )

```
{% name_of_your_function_from_that_script %}
```

This code will run the simple_tag every single request as I said.

2. without simple_tag within 1 function in your views.py

Here the other way around a user have to hit a specific URL in order to write cookies into your database.

Codes:

```
def your_function(request):
    """
    blablabla
    """
    cookies = request.cookies["cart"]

    # Codes for creating a new line into your models
    ...
```